# How to conditionally apply a GraphQL filter based on the value of a passed in argument?

Tags: filter, graphql, gatsby

**Update:** for my particular use case, @langpavel's solution will work. However, it avoids answering the original question... *is it possible to conditionally apply a GraphQL filter based on the value of a passed in argument?*

I am passing in an argument into my GraphQL query called `$env` that I would like to use in conjunction with a `draft` boolean in the markdown frontmatter of my blog posts in order to filter out drafts during production.

My query, in an abbreviated form, is below. As you can see, I have a filter function that is filtering based on whether the blog post is a draft or not. What I can't figure out how to do is take advantage of the `$env` argument to only apply the filter when `$env` is equal to `production`.

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPosts($env: String!) {
    markdownRemark(
      filter: { frontmatter: { draft: { eq: true } } }
    ) {
      frontmatter {
        title
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        draft
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of gatsby, you should probably write two queries and select one conditionally based on `process.env.NODE_ENV`:

```
export const pageQuery = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ?
graphql`
  query BlogPosts {
    markdownRemark(
      filter: { frontmatter: { draft: { ne: true } } }
    ) { frontmatter { ... } }
  }
` : graphql`
  query BlogPosts {
    markdownRemark { frontmatter { ... } }
  }
`
```

Comment: Excellent idea, but unfortunately node env's such as `process.env` are not available at the time the Gatsby runtime extracts and processes your GraphQL queries

Comment: Yes, they are and `process.env.NODE_ENV` especially: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#reserved-environment-variables

Comment: This doesn't work, Gatsby tells you that you have multiple root queries in development if you try this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The GraphQL query you provided is invalid because the $env variable is not used in any fields. I think for your purpose, `$env` would be better passed outside of the GraphQL query. If you're serving GraphQL over HTTP, you could send it as a query parameter or an HTTP header. Then you could pass the value to your GraphQL resolvers using the `context` concept that most GraphQL libraries provide.

Comment: Hi Rob. Unfortunately the filtering has to happen from within the query itself because of the way the Gatsby runtime processes your GraphQL queries. True, the query I provided may not technically be valid, but that is only because I was including the `$env` argument for demonstration purposes. I'm hoping someone on here can help show me how to properly use `$env` in conjunction with the filter, if that's even possible